# Is there a way to add return to a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I just want to know if it is possible for me to return activePodcastViewData. I get return not allow here anytime I tried to call it on the activePodcastViewData.Without the GlobalScope I do get everything working fine.However I updated my repository by adding suspend method to it.Hence I was getting Suspend function should only be called from a coroutine or another suspend function.

fun getPodcast(podcastSummaryViewData: PodcastViewModel.PodcastSummaryViewData): PodcastViewData? {
val repo = podcastRepo ?: return null
val url = podcastSummaryViewData.url ?: return null

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
                val podcast = repo.getPodcast(url)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    podcast?.let {
                        it.feedTitle = podcastViewData.name ?: ""
                        it.imageUrl = podcastViewData.imageUrl ?: ""
                        activePodcastViewData = PodcastView(it)
                        activePodcastViewData
                    }
                }
            }
            return null
        }
```

class PodcastRepo {
val rssFeedService =RssFeedService.instance

```
suspend fun getPodcast(url:String):Podcast?{
    rssFeedService.getFeed(url)
    return Podcast(url,"No name","No Desc","No image")
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call return?

Comment: @Francesc initially when I click a podcast I get its details displayed. However Nothing is displayed now.I rather get an error log pop up on my screen saying "Error Lodaing https://........."

Comment: Please share more code to see how this coroutine is launched - but there should be no return at the end of the coroutine.

Comment: @Francesc please can you check my code agin I have edited it.

Comment: We really need the code that is outside of `GlobalScope.launch()`, not inside it. What do you need this `return null` for? What would be wrong if you would just remove this line? When the execution arrives at this line, it will return anyway.

Comment: @broot please take a look now I have added the complete method

Comment: You cannot use `GlobalScope.launch` here because launch is a fire and forget call, it does not return the result, it retuns a Job immediately that you can then join or cancel or whatnot. you should change your getPodcast method to be a suspend method instead.

Comment: Ok @Francesc you right. However If I do that it does affect other part of the code.Its pretty large.Thanks for the direction.Much appreciated.

Comment: As `rssFeedService.getFeed(url)` is a long-running operation, all functions that are "above" it and wait for its results are also long-running. Now, you need to choose what to do with such long-running code. You can make it suspendable, but that means making functions above it also suspendable. You can block the thread (replace `GlobalScope.lanuch()` with `runBlocking()`), but note you should not block some threads. Or you can redesign your code to use futures/deferred or callbacks, but this is also quite a lot of work. There is no universal way, you need to choose something.

Comment: You said that you just updated your repository and added this suspend function. Why other functions don't need to be suspendable, but this one does? Do other functions receive data from different sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly but if you want to get activePodcastViewData from coroutine scope you should use some observable data holder.  I will show you a simple example with [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

At first, add implementation:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"
```

Now, in your ViewModel we need to create mutableLiveData to hold and emit our future data.

```
val podcastsLiveData by lazy { MutableLiveData<Podcast>() }
```

Here your method: (I wouldn't recommend GlobalScope, let's replace it)

```
fun getPodcast(podcastSummaryViewData: PodcastViewModel.PodcastSummaryViewData): PodcastViewData? {
    val repo = podcastRepo ?: return null
    val url = podcastSummaryViewData.url ?: return null
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val podcast = repo.getPodcast(url)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            podcast?.let {
                it.feedTitle = podcastViewData.name ?: ""
                it.imageUrl = podcastViewData.imageUrl ?: ""
                activePodcastViewData = PodcastView(it)
            }
        }
    }
    podcastsLiveData.postValue(activePodcastViewData)
}
```

As you can see your return null is turned to postValue(). Now you finally can observe this from your Activity:

```
viewModel.podcastsLiveData.observe(this) {
            val podcast = it
            //Use your data
        }
viewModel.getPodcast()
```

Now every time you call **viewModel.getPodcast()** method, code in **observe** will be invoked.

I hope that I helped some :D